# Was Casandra secretly intended to be Rapunzel's bodyguard?

Tags: character, rapunzels-tangled-adventure

In the Disney Channel original series "Rapunzel's Tangled Adventure", was Casandra's position as Rapunzel's handmaid a cover for her being a bodyguard, or did her father truly intend for her to be a handmaid?

Can this be confirmed in any canonical sources?